# how to allow - in preg replace

Tags: youtube, preg-replace

ok so I have basically finished building my first module with quite a bit of help from this site.

I have fully tested the module and it works awesomely however because the module is about embedding videos and one of them of course is YouTube.

the problem I am having is that some YouTube videos use `-` in there video key and I am having a problem with getting preg_replace to recognize it as it is used as a through for like `0-9` or `a-z` and this is where the problem comes in.

how can I extinguish `-` as its own character that `preg_replace` needs to recognize

I have tried `preg_replace('#[^a-z_-0-9]#i', '', $_POST['youtube']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't put the dash next to a range like 0-9

```
preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_-]#i', '', $_POST['youtube']);
```